# How to handle onEndReached within SectionList in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-sectionlist

Does anyone know how to handle the onEndReached prop for the Section List? Since it contains 2 lists and I have 2 sections.. How it is possible to react for the variant lists?

Comment: Did you find a solution @realarb?